# How to integration Blockchain Payment API in Asp.Net?

Tags: api, blockchain.info

I am new to using the Blockchain API. I have tried several times to use
`https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$password&second_password=$second_password&to=$to&amount=$amount`
but it always redirects me to https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api instead.

I don't understand why it doesn't give any response.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're new to API.

The link you gave,
    `https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$password&second_password=$second_password&to=$to&amount=$amount`

Is only a template for an API request. You need to swap out the `$guid` with your merchant wallet id, e.g.

```
4b8cd8e9-9480-44cc-b7f2-527e98ee3287
```

You also need to substitute every other variable starting with a $ with the respective information.

```
e.g. password=<insert password here>
```

Comment: Many time i try it on browser but it redirect to https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api page

Comment: This means that you are still using the API wrongly.